# Sqlite exception near "FOREIGN"?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

```
  String CREATE_SUBCATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SUBCATEGORY_LIST+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DESC + " TEXT,"+ KEY_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_CONTENT1+" TEXT,"+ KEY_CONTENTTYPE1 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT2+" TEXT,"+ KEY_CONTENTTYPE2 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT3+" TEXT,"+ KEY_CONTENTTYPE3 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT4+" TEXT,"+ KEY_CONTENTTYPE4 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT5+" TEXT,"+ KEY_CONTENTTYPE5 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT6+" TEXT,"+ KEY_CONTENTTYPE6 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ORDERID+" INTEGER,"+ KEY_STATUS+" TEXT,"
            + KEY_UPDATED+" TEXT, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+"("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+")";
```

I am getting the following error now:-

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE subcategory_list(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,subcategory_name TEXT,subcategory_shdesc TEXT,category_id INTEGER,content1 TEXT,content_type1 TEXT,content2 TEXT,content_type2 TEXT,content3 TEXT,content_type3 TEXT,content4 TEXT,content_type4 TEXT,content5 TEXT,content_type5 TEXT,content6 TEXT,content_type6 TEXT,order_id INTEGER,status TEXT,updated TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category_list(category_id)
```

Can anyone point out my mistake. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `KEY_UPDATED+"TEXT" +" FOREIGN KEY` Before `TEXT`, you have to insert a space. Otherwise the outcome would be `UpdatedkeyTEXT`

Comment: You're still missing one close paren `)` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fix some typos in the last line:

```
+ KEY_UPDATED + " TEXT," //added , and space
+" FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_CATEGORY_ID + ") REFERENCES " 
+ CAT_TABLE + "("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+"))"; //added "CREATE TABLE closing parenthesis"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a Space before and a comma after `"TEXT"` in the last line.

You also have to close the last bracket.

Your last line would look correctly like this:

```
+ KEY_UPDATED+" TEXT," +" FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+"("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+"))";
```

You can also omit the " + " between TEXT and FOREIGN KEY, because you're just joining two strings.

```
+ KEY_UPDATED+" TEXT, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+"("+KEY_CATEGORY_ID+"))";
```

Comment: So you added the Space before " TEXT" and the comma after? And you're still getting exactly the same error?

Comment: I get this error now android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1)